# Is it possible to have Leksah use a cabal-dev environment for it's workspace?

Tags: haskell, cabal, leksah, cabal-dev

I'm trying to make sure I don't enter dependency hell by using cabal-dev and I'm also trying to use leksah for my IDE. However, when adding packages to the local workspace in leksah, it build and installs the packages to my user ~/.cabal package space.

How can I force leksah to install package dependencies to the cabal-dev environment i've setup?

Comment: I'm guessing you installed Leksah using `cabal install leksah`;am I correct?

Comment: Actually I installed it with apt on ubuntu.

Comment: You might want to consider trying `cabal-dev install leksah`, this might actually solve your problem, but can't be sure since I use cabal myself. Though this might entail an `apt get remove leksah`, purge, etc. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @eazar001 Then leksah would be locked to working with only one dev environment. I would need to re-install a fresh copy of my IDE into every project I want to work on. pass. there has to be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not the quick and clean solution that you were looking for, but.... there is a development version of leksah available that has 'experimental cabal-dev' support. If you go through the `src` directory a little bit, and inspect the relevant files, you will see that there is an option added to the IDE preference menu, allowing you to use cabal-dev. Also has some updated code to install dependencies accordingly as well. The link is here:

https://github.com/leksah/leksah

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thankyou, This helps. Now I can go and build it once and use it everywhere.